Boot problem with 20.04 and 24.04
I recently installed a new SSD and installed Ubuntu 20.04 but ran into problems when the installation was complete and I restarted the computer. The computer did not boot as expected but returned again and again to the box with selectable options where the new SSD was included.
After many failed attempts, I created a stick with the latest version, 24.04 and redid the installation. Unfortunately the result was the same, the computer does not boot.
There are no problems with starting the installation from the USB stick and trying Ubuntu, there were also no problems booting from the SSD when Windows 10 was installed. I chose to have Windows 10 deleted when I installed Ubuntu.
The computer is a laptop, Fujitsu Lifebook S series Model SH531 with 8 GB RAM.
What can cause this problem and how can it be solved?

Seems Fujitsu has some issues. Mostly older info, but similar models, so may have some help. Workarounds, details on UEFI issues & links to most of old posts
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2496872
Investigating a vanishing BIOS on the Fujitsu LIFEBOOK AH532 &
https://blog.timschumi.net/2024/01/20/ah532-bios-investigation.html
https://github.com/timschumi/ah532-biostools Fujitsu laptop  LH532 cold boot to reset system
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2407207 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2257720
